# Remove spaces from string after and before letter

Tags: python, regex, trim, spaces

I have a quite a few sums of strings that look like this: "a name / another name / something else".

I want to get to this: "a name/another name/something else".

Basically removing the spaces before and after the forward slashes only (not between the words themselves).

I know nothing about programming but I looked and found that this can be done with Python and Regex. I was a bit overwhelmed though with the amount of information I found.

Comment: maybe [`re.sub(r' +/ +', '/', str)`](https://regex101.com/r/Crnzow/1) suffices.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the pattern:

```
(?:(?<=\/) | (?=\/))
```

- `(?:` Non capturing group.
- `(?<=\/)` Lookbehind for `/`.
- `|` OR
- `(?=\/)` Positive lookahead for `/`.
- `)` Close non capturing group.

You can try it live [here](https://regex101.com/r/2iTCVo/1).

---

Python snippet:

```
import re
str = 'a name / another name / something else'
print(re.sub(r'(?:(?<=\/) | (?=\/))','',str))
```

Prints:

```
a name/another name/something else
```

Answer (score 2):

There's no need for regex here, since you're simply replacing a string of literals.

```
str = "a name / another name / something else"
print(str.replace(" / ", "/"))
```

Comment: What if there exist more than one whitespace?!

Comment: @AmirRezazadeh There could be any number of potential typos in the input. What if there are more than one forward slashes? What if there's a random letter in between the space and the slash? OP didn't ask about this issue, so my answer didn't account for it.

Comment: @CAustin Then read the question again, cuz it’s about removing spaces not just one space.

Comment: @AmirRezazadeh It says "the spaces before and after" which to me simply indicates the two spaces on either side of the forward slash.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an answer without using regex that I feel is easier to understand

```
string = "a name / another name / something else"
edited = "/".join([a.strip() for a in string.split("/")])
print(edited)
```

output:

```
a name/another name/something else
```

---

`.join()` joins elements of a sequence by a given seperator, [docs](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_join.htm)

`.strip()` removes beginning and trailing whitespace, [docs](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_strip.htm)

`.split()` splits the string into tokens by character, [docs](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_split.htm)

Answer (score 0):

This pattern will match for any amount of whitespace surrounding `/` and remove it. I think the regex is relatively easy to understand

```
\s*([\/])\s*
```

Has a capturing group that matches the backslash (that's what the middle part is). The `s*` parts match whitespace (at least one up to any amount of times).

You can then replace these matched strings with just a `/` to get rid of all the whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

`str1` being your string:

```
re.sub(" / ", "/" ,str1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code to remove all spaces before and after the `/` character:

```
import re
str = 'a name /  another name / something else'
str = re.sub(r'(?:(?<=\/)\s*|\s*(?=\/))','', str)
```

Check [this document](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) for more information.